# pyspark taking a log of column

Tags: python, pyspark

```
length = df.count()
df = df.withColumn("log", log(col("power"),lit(length)))
```

The following lines throw such an error. Can you please help me take a log of a column using another value or another column as a base.

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-c0894b6127d1> in <module>()
      1 #df.show()
      2 
----> 3 df = df.withColumn("log", log(col("power"),lit(2)))

5 frames
/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in __iter__(self)
    342 
    343     def __iter__(self):
--> 344         raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
    345 
    346     # string methods

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use funtions that are not build-in on spark dataframes you can use user-defined functions, in your case it would look like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from math import log

@udf("float")
def log_udf(s):
  return log(s,2)

df.withColumn("log", log_udf("power")).show()
```